# Select max value in one column for every value in the other column

Tags: r, group-by, max

I have a dataframe `competition` with columns `branch`, `phone` and `sales`

```
| branch   | phone   | sales|
|----------|---------|------|
| 123      | milky   | 654  |
| 456      | lemon   | 342  |
| 789      | blue    | 966  |
| 456      | blue    | 100  |
| 456      | milky   | 234  |
| 123      | lemon   | 874  |
| 789      | milky   | 234  |
| 123      | blue    | 332  |
| 789      | lemon   | 865  |
```

I want to show the highest number of sales for every phone:
The output should be a dataframe `winners` that look like this

```
| branch   | phone   | sales|
|----------|---------|------|
| 123      | milky   | 654  |
| 789      | blue    | 966  |
| 123      | lemon   | 874  |
```

I tried order a dataframe by `sales` first, and then left only 3 top rows,

```
competition <- competition[order(competition$sales, decreasing = TRUE ),]
winners <- head(competition, 3)
```

But the output shows `lemon` phone two times with 874 and 865 `sales`

Comment: `winners <- competition %>% group_by(phone) %>% slice(which.max(sales))` using `dplyr`.

Answer (score 1):

```
aggregrate(sales ~ phone, df, max)
```

Comment: Thank you for this code snippet, which might provide some limited, immediate help. A [proper explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762/9193372) would greatly improve its long-term value by showing why this is a good solution to the problem and would make it more useful to future readers with other, similar questions. Please edit your answer to add some explanation.